# Visual Studio 2015 not running C++ unit tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

This is weird.

Firstly, loading the solution doesn't detect the two unit tests - I have to modify the unit test and do a rebuild for the tests to appear in test explorer.

Once I've done that, I can run a unit test ONCE. After that, I get:

```
Message: Failed to set up the execution context to run the test
```

How did it run the test the first time and not the subsequent times? Using depends.exe I can see there's one file missing: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.x64.dll. I tried copying this file to the output directory but it made no difference.

The output directory contains all the files required by the main application to run, so all I've done is place the unit test DLL in that same directory. The test runs once then all subsequent runs die.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. On the Test menu, Test Settings turn OFF Keep Test Execution Engine Running. Now I can run any test as much as I need to.